# Bizarre MySQL behavior when trying to aggregate results using MAX()

Tags: mysql

So the following query that I'm using produces 4 rows:

```
SELECT 
  `DMV`.`id` AS `dmvID`,
  `D`.`id` AS `documentID`,
  `DMV`.`name` AS `documentName`,
  `U`.`username` AS `creatorUserName`,
  `D`.`folder_id` AS `folderID`,
  `D`.`created` AS `createDate`,
  `SL`.`name` AS `statusName`,
  `UM`.`username` AS `modifiedUserName`,
  `DMV`.`version_created` AS `modifiedDate`,
  `UO`.`username` AS `ownerUserName`,
  `DTL`.`name` AS `documentTypeName` 
FROM 
  `document_metadata_version` `DMV`
  LEFT JOIN `documents` `D` 
    ON `DMV`.`document_id` = `D`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `users` `U` 
    ON `D`.`creator_id` = `U`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `users` `UM` 
    ON `D`.`modified_user_id` = `UM`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `users` `UO` 
    ON `D`.`owner_id` = `UO`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `status_lookup` `SL` 
    ON `D`.`status_id` = `SL`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `document_types_lookup` `DTL` 
    ON `DMV`.`document_type_id` = `DTL`.`id`
WHERE
    DMV.document_id = 543433
;
```

For the sake of brevity, I'll omit all the irrelevant fields not related to the question at hand.  The results of `dmvID` and `documentTypeName` (first and last columns) are:

```
+--------+------------------+
| dmvID  | documentTypeName |
+--------+------------------+
| 566053 | Default          |
| 566183 | Default          |
| 681391 | ASCO Documents   |
| 681411 | ASCO Documents   |
+--------+------------------+
```

I'm only interesting in the last row, so naturally, I'll modify the SELECT statement to use MAX() on `dmvID`:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(`DMV`.`id`) AS `dmvID`,
# Rest of query unchanged
```

That returns:

```
+--------+------------------+
| dmvID  | documentTypeName |
+--------+------------------+
| 681411 | Default          |
+--------+------------------+
```

Note from above that 681411 is in fact the MAX(), but the associated `documentTypeName` is not the equivalent value for `dmvID` 681411, I would assume it's matching it to `dmvID` 566053.  How do I get it to return:

```
+--------+------------------+
| dmvID  | documentTypeName |
+--------+------------------+
| 681411 | ASCO Documents   |
+--------+------------------+
```

Comment: And you only need exactly one row from this entire query (i.e. you will not use the other three)?

Comment: That is correct, I only need one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need the single row with the highest value in that column, use ORDER BY and LIMIT 1 (instead of an aggregating query using MAX()).

```
...
WHERE
DMV.document_id = 543433
ORDER BY dmvID DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Oddly enough, that still returns the same unexpected results, for `dmvID` 681411, and "Default", not "ASCO Documents" for `documentTypeName`.

Comment: Ah, guess I jumped the gun and went straight to the SQL.  That worked!  Thanks!

Comment: Also, since I can't mark your answer as the accepted solution for another 5 minutes, any chance you could explain why MAX() was causing that behavior and LIMIT doesn't?  Just curious.

Comment: Sure! The difference is in the meaning of the term "aggregating". Anytime you use an "aggregate" function in a query (such as MAX, COUNT, GROUP_CONCAT, etc.), MySQL tries to mash up every row, and return some kind of aggregated data based on the entire column. With the LIMIT query (IF you remove MAX), you are not causing any aggregation, which means your rows are left intact and not mashed together.